# mousedown event doesn't get called on longpress

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a small library in which I have an input which when focussed, can't be blurred by clicking/tapping a specific div (by returning false on the mousedown event). Other elements are fine (normal behavior). Mentioned div contains in the actual implementation a few buttons which add text to the input field. The focus is not required for that to work, but I want keyboard input accepted there as well, so I want it to work the way I explained.

I noticed somewhat strange behavior on mobile though.
When longpressing (click and hold a few hundred ms) the unclickable div whilst focussed on the input, the mousedown event doesn't occur and the blur event magically triggers. I noticed that another event did not occur either, so it's not only the mousedown event.

Example:

```
<input id="input" type="text" />

<div id="disabledArea" class="flex-center">
Blur disabled when clicking here.
</div>
```

With the following JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var disabledArea = document.getElementById('disabledArea');

input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    console.log("blur");
});

disabledArea.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    console.log("mousedown");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pgukmmjo/

Can anybody help me with this? It's kinda hard to explain, but very obvious once you understand the problem.

I recommend the example JSFiddle to be viewed in Chrome with DevTools open (`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `I`) and device toolbar on (`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `M`) which simulates mobile touch. Alternatively you can change the console logs with alerts and view it on mobile.

Comment: It is probably the `touchstart` event that is being triggered before the `blur` event, when holding down the mouse.

Comment: @DavidDomain, I figured that too, since it's only happening on mobile touch devices. Cancelling out that event type does resolve the issue, however I need touch to work within that div, since I've got a few buttons in there which add stuff to the input and however focus isn't necessarily required for that to work, I want it to work that way. Thanks for commenting.